# Need to make print an array in the form of a matrix. In a "snake" pattern

Tags: java

How to make square matrix appear in a "snake" pattern? User inputs # of rows/columns in array and then matrix is displayed in ascending order but in a snake pattern.

```
 1  2  3  4
 8  7  6  5
 9 10 11 12
16 15 14 13
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A3_Q2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("[-------------------------]");
        System.out.println("[      Array Pattern      ]");
        System.out.println("[-------------------------]");

        System.out.println("How many rows/columns do you want your array to have? (Mist be at least 3):");


        int arraySize = keyboard.nextInt();

        while(arraySize < 3) 
        {
            System.out.println("Lets try this again ....");
            System.out.println("How many rows/columns do you want your array to have? (Mist be at least 3):");
            arraySize = keyboard.nextInt(); 
        }


        int [][] pattern = new int[arraySize][arraySize];



        int number = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i <= arraySize -1; i++){

            for(int j = 0; j <= arraySize - 1; j++)
            {
                pattern[i][j] = number;
                number++;
                System.out.printf("%3d", pattern[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please add sample input and output.

Answer (score 0):

If we wanted to just print the 2D array in ascending order from left to right on each row, we could just use the following `for` loop:

```
for (int i=0; i < arraySize; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j < arraySize; ++j) {
        System.out.printf("%3d", pattern[i][j]);
    }
}
```

To get the reverse order effect you want, we only need to add logic such that for *odd* rows, we print a row backwards, from left to right:

```
for (int i=0; i < arraySize; ++i) {
    if (i%2 == 0) {
        // for even rows, print as we normally would
        for (int j=0; j < arraySize; ++j) {
            System.out.printf("%3d", pattern[i][j]);
        }
    }
    else {
        // for odd rows, iterate backwards over the array, the print left to right
        for (int j=arraySize-1; j >= 0; --j) {
            System.out.printf("%3d", pattern[i][j]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Update:**

You can initialize your array using something like the following:

```
int arraySize = 4;
for (int i=0; i < arraySize; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j < arraySize; ++j) {
        pattern[i][j] = i*arraySize + j + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually tried this right after I asked, for some reason still not working. Going to play around and try to figure it out. Thanks for the help and letting me know I'm on the right track

Comment: @Mike Maybe reload your page, I made a small edit after my initial post.  I have tested locally using IntelliJ, and it works.  Perhaps your code has other problems besides this.

Comment: but what about the number integer that increases by 1 each time?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  I have given you code which meets the requirements you originally gave us.

Comment: just saying in your code you haven't assigned a value to the array so when you print, you get all zeros

Comment: @Mike I gave you code for initializing the 2D array.